# How to create a vector of structs and initialize them later

Tags: c++, qt, vector

For easier handling I want to create a vector of self-defined elements which I can easily access afterwards via `A[0]` and so on. The problem is that each element has a non-empty constructor, i.e. I can't write

```
elem A;
```

instead I have to write

```
elem A(int a, int b, int c);
```

during creation with a, b, c fixed values. But that is not possible for me, because I get the values of these elements during runtime.
So, is there a way to do something like that:

```
Vector<elem> A;
elem B(int a, int b, int c);
A.push_back(B);
```

And if yes, how?
As explanation: `Vector` can either be `std::vector` or `QVector`, but both of them lead to a problem, either crashing during compilation time or during runtime.
EDIT: 
Complete code:

```
#ifndef DPC_H
#define DPC_H
#include "../BlackLib/v2_0/BlackGPIO.h"
#include <QVector>


class DPC
{
private:
    QVector<BlackLib::BlackGPIO> A;
public:
    DPC();
    ~DPC();
};

#endif // DPC_H


#include "dpc.h"


    DPC::DPC()
    {
        BlackLib::BlackGPIO Pin(BlackLib::BlackGPIO(BlackLib::GPIO_32, BlackLib::input));
        /*DPC::A[0] = new */A.push_back(Pin);
        A.push_back(Pin);
        /*DPC::A[1] = new B*/A.push_back(BlackLib::BlackGPIO(BlackLib::GPIO_33, BlackLib::input));

    }
```

BlackLib is a data type for a BBB pin extention from https://github.com/yigityuce/BlackLib

SOLUTION:
Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BlackLib::BlackGPIO> > A;`

Comment: Yes, and I got an error telling me that "candidate expects 3 arguments, got 0".

Comment: In which piece of code?

Comment: In `Vector<elem> A;`

Comment: That should not require `elem` to be DefaultConstructible. Demo: http://ideone.com/159D9Q

Comment: That's not "complete code", see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What should I add more? Headers? If you really want to have the complete code, that would be more than 1000 lines of code...

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and come up with something like http://ideone.com/159D9Q that shows the problem (which that link already shows should not be a problem)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: <NOT WORKING> I could already solve the problem, my problem was that I first used `QVector`, but this type of vector does not provide something like `emplace_back` and handles things appearently a bit different than std::vector. When using std::vector everything works. Should I though provide some more code? <NOT WORKING> I am going to work on providing full code

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ok, full code added, I hope everything is correct now

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the MCVE link, or missed the "Minimal" part. If your problem was with `QVector` then why did you ask about `std::vector`? That just wastes everyone's time. Next time spend five minutes to confirm that the problem you're describing actually exists.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: My problem exists with both variants of Vector, with QVector I get the error mentioned above, with std::vector my program crashes on startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very nearly exactly the way you wrote, in fact. You can do

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<B> A;
B foo(a, b, c);
A.push_back(foo);
```

Or, if you have a sufficiently recent compiler that knows C++11,

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<B> A;
A.emplace_back(a, b, c);
```

The latter saves a copy (the object is constructed directly inside the vector), so it is better™. Although, as @JonathanWakely points out in the comments, care must be taken to maintain exception safety with `emplace_back`, in that

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B> > vec;

vec.emplace_back(new B); // is not exception-safe if the vector has to 
                         // relocate and might throw bad_alloc, in which case
                         // the newly allocated foo object is leaked because
                         // no one is responsible for cleaning it up.

vec.push_back(new B);    // does not compile
```

This is easily fixed in the case of a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<...>>`:

```
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());     // C++14
vec.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<B>(new B)); // C++11

// these also work and do the same thing with push_back
```

...but you have to remember to do it.

Comment: I am not familiar with BlackLib, but a cursory glance at the code leads me to believe that it is not equipped for this use case. The BlackGPIO class holds a naked pointer to heap data but has no user-defined copy or move constructors. This later leads to a double free. Really this should be fixed in BlackLib, but as a workaround you could use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BlackLib::BlackGPIO> >` and do `A.emplace_back(new BlackLib::BlackGPIO(...));`

Comment: That means I have to add my own constructors?

Comment: Do I have to free something afterwards (because of using new?) I'm not so familiar with unique_ptr, therefore I am asking (when using only vectors I don't have to free something).

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` does that for you -- that's its sole purpose in life.

Comment: @Wintermute, `emplace_back(new ...)` is not exception-safe if the vector tries to reallocate and throws `bad_alloc`

Comment: @JonathanWakely You're absolutely right. I added a paragraph reflecting that.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to do something like that:
>
> ```
>  vector<elem> A;
>  elem B(int a, int b, int c);
>  A.push_back(B);
> ```
>
> And if yes, how?

Yes. There are a few possibilities. First, check out emplace_back. It is similar to push back, but the arguments passed directly to the constructor of the held object (perfect forwarding):

```
vector<elem> A;
A.emplace_back(a, b, c); // for an existing elem::elem(int a, int b, int c)
```

You can also rely on the copy constructor of elem, to construct n elements after a model:

```
elem model{ a, b, c };
vector<elem> A{ 10, model }; // create 10 elements equal to model
```